# div-Block height depends from content inside

Tags: html, css

everyone!
I got a problem with changing height of block when form height inside it becomes more(maybe it's only looks like so,don't know).
My sample on http://jsfiddle.net/vXNCD

Maybe I have this problem, because I gave position for `form` using

```
position: relative;
    left: 13em;
    top: 9em;
```

If it's so, how to make positioning correctly?
How make my `#content`  covering all `inputs` ??

Comment: You are setting `position:relative` which takes that element out the flow of the page

Comment: `position: absolute` takes element out of the flow...A relative positioned element is positioned relative to its normal position

Comment: @Scott as far as i know, `position:relative` doesn't take an element out of normal flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to position your form a little offside, use padding in the parent element instead of position relative.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vXNCD/13/

What i did was remove position relative and add padding to #content div plus added box-sizing to make sure padding is counted as a part of width.

```
#content
{
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 30em;
    background-color: rgba(62,96,111,0.9);
    position: relative;
    margin: 5em auto;

    -webkit-border-radius: 0.42em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.42em;
    -o-border-radius: 0.42em;
    -ms-border-radius: 0.42em;
    border-radius: 0.42em;

    padding: 9em 13em;    

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that this is the best decision of the problem in my situation

Comment: Glade i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `padding-bottom: 9em` to `#content > form`. The value should be equal to or greater than `top: 9em`. In this way your form will stay inside the block. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMqL9/).

```
#content > form
{
    position: relative;
    left: 13em;
    top: 9em;
    padding-bottom: 9em;
}
```

Or better, you should use `padding-top: 9em` instead of `top: 9em` so you avoid this problem altogether. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9hqA/).

```
#content > form
{
    position: relative;
    left: 13em;
    padding-top: 9em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your element is positioned relative. Use padding to position the contents instead of top and left.

```
    #content > form {
    position: relative;
    padding: 40px 60px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to get the form within the box, I don't see why you should use relative positioning at all. Just removing it, you will be fine. Then you can center the content (if you wish) with margin : 0 auto; where it's needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/9jNZG/

```
#content
{
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 30em;
    background-color: rgba(62,96,111,0.9);
    margin: 5em auto;
    padding:1em;
}
```

Just added some padding to make it look a little better with some breathing room :), and of course. Removed the relative positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the following styles,

## content > form

{

```
position: relative;
left: 13em;
top: 9em;
```

}

What you are doing here is adjusting the form with respect(RELATIVE) to the #content,Then changing the left and top positions.
By default,the position of an element is static..Thus the #content will cover all the form data.